# How to fix a error "Permission denied" when trying to push to a live server?

Tags: git, ssh

```
error: Unable to append to ./logs/refs/heads/master: Permission denied
To ssh://franssano@ola-10.sbc.com/var/www/www.super-life.se
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to write)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://franssano@ola-10.sbc.com/var/www/www.super-life.se'
```

Comment: Arrange to have permission?